# Running an excel macro using rubyXL

Tags: ruby, rubyxl

I am using rubyXL version 3.3.16. I and trying to interact with a .xlsm document to perform data read/write.
There is also a macro within the worksheet which I need to run at the end. Is there a way I could run the excel macros using rubyXL version 3.3.16 ?
Below is my code to access the excel and the worksheet:

```
require 'rubyXL'

workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("abc.xlsm")            
myWorksheet = workbook[0]
```

Please help on how to run any existing macros in the workbook.